# Conditioned sum function in report

Tags: ms-access, sum, ms-access-2016

Regarding MS Access, I need to add a Text box on a report that gets sum of a field conditional to another field value.
I.e.
I have a field named [clinic] another one named [clinic_income].
How can I calculate SUM of [clinic_income] only if [clinic] value = Dental clinic?

I tried this formula but it didn't work

```
Sum(
    Filter(
           'ALL' 
            Clinic = clinicInput. Dental clinic), 
Clinic_income)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what IIf() is for:

`=Sum(IIf([Clinic] = "Dental", [clinic_income], Null))`